Search a particular word in every table data and automatically list it in a column
I'm kinda new with formulas in Google Sheet and was wondering how can I pull this. I have a sheet where I get to list down different tables with different Keyword on a single row. For example, Keyword:Here, or on another table Keyword:There. I wanted to be able to filter all this titles with 'keyword'on it and be able to list it all down in another sheet.
For reference, I have prepared a Practice sheet.
I was only manually adding this together with their data. Means, from one sheet, I'll just put = then refer to the cell I wanted to import the value. I was wondering if we have any formula we can use that even if I add new table with "Keyword:xx" everyday, it'll automatically imported to another sheet.


You may try:
=iferror(choosecols(filter('Sheet 1'!$27:$27,scan(,'Sheet 1'!$2:$2,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c)))=A6),2,3,4))


To pull the whole list automatically:
=reduce(tocol(,1),'Sheet 1'!A2:index('Sheet 1'!2:2,match(,0/('Sheet 1'!4:4<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,if(c="",tocol(,1),hstack(c,offset(c,25,1,,3))))))


Explanation:

'Sheet 1'!A2:index('Sheet 1'!2:2,match(,0/('Sheet 1'!4:4<>""))) dynamically translates to A2:L2 because that's where the table data ends as of now
Now if a cell in row_2 is blank → Do Nothing [tocol(,1) is a null value within vstack()] → Otherwise output the values present at a certain offset offset(c,25,1,,3)
Look into reduce() explanation here to get a bit more clear picture on what it does



Hi. May I ask how did you breakdown the whole formula you used?

Added some basic explanation part to the answer section...

Hi. I was able to make the formula you gave work, but I was having trouble determining the offset value offset(c,25,1,,3) hence, the total result was not listed on my end (Values on B27:D27 based on my practice sheet)

If you have some time, can you please look at the "Based on Real Format" sheet I've included on my Practice Sheet for you to be able to understand the total count of my rows. Thank you so so much!!

Found a way by trying multiple offsets in my formula. Thank you so much for your help! <3
